# How to change speed of the chapter transition in mapbox storytelling?

Tags: mapbox

I am using the basic example provided on GitHub with `config.js` and `index.html` and `helper.html` files, but I can't figure out where to put the speed parameter to change the flyTo animation move slowly.

Answer (score 1):

ok I found the answer: you just need to add 'speed' attribute to a location field which was counterintuitive for me because of the docs said you have to do it in flyTo options. But I found this example that helped: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/scroll-fly-to/